# How do I map rolling past seven days against each date in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let us assume there are two date fields in a table: for_date and from_date.
I want something like 
below as an output by writing the query:
[image]

- For every date in for_date, it should return the for_date, followed by past 6 dates
- SI no is provided as a reference to this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Got it. Would keep in mind from next time. Thanks

Comment: And please use a sensible date format (ISO would do fine)

Answer (score 0):

How about `generate_series()`?

```
select t.for_date, g.from_date
from t, lateral
     generate_series(for_date - interval '6 day', for_date, interval '1 day') g(from_date)
```